# Database: Storing calculation value vs calculate each request

Tags: database-design

Hello I have this dilemma about storing calculated value or just calculate the value each requests.

the application requires millions of rows (it's a shareholder based application) to be calculated but I came across the DRY principles which stated that we shouldn't keep any duplicates.

There are pros and cons with both methods yet for the business perspective (keeping cost low yet data integrity is ensured), What kind of method should I use or are there any alternatives?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally you have to weigh the cost / benefit. If you frontload the calculations and store their results they will always be out of date. If you put your entire system in lockstep and update calculations on a clearly defined schedule at sensisble time intervals and the application can handle slightly outdated information, that's a good options. If you HAVE to be on the bleeding edge, you must crunch the data in real time which is expensive and can incur hardware costs if you need more processing power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DRY is in regards to source code more than database design.

It is a normal pattern to have for example a table with

Raw data (all) -> Hourly aggregated data -> Daily aggregated data etc

You need to think about what sort of logical format your data fits in.

Other possible solutions are:

View - Create a view table that calculates the values and have your client access the view (that way you wont have to physically store the calculations).

Server/Client Side Cache - Calculate the values on the client side and depending on the lifetime of the calculations set a relevant cache time.